# Start AlarmManager on button click

Tags: java, android, alarm, android-alarms

I want to start an AlarManager when a button is pressed. The problem is: The AM starts when I start the app :/

My Code:

```
public void scheduleAlarm()
    {  
            int time = 10 * 1000;

            intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);

            alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    }
```

And I try to call this in a onClickListener of a button. But it starts from beginning of activity :/

Can anyone help me?

Comment: When do you call your `scheduleAlarm()`?

Comment: in onClickListener of a button

Comment: also keep in mind, that your start time is less than System.currentTimeMillis(), so your alarm will fire as soon as you set it

Comment: but time is 10000 and 10000 is less than System.currentTimeMillis() or am I wrong? :o

Comment: in case of RTC_WAKEUP start time is absolute time in milliseconds (like Aug 19 2013 15:22 but in ms), it's not a relative period of time in which alarm fires. So you should use `System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 1000` as your start time, and 10 * 1000 as your intervals

Comment: By the way, do you have other alarms in your app?

Comment: no just this one, ok I try it :)

Comment: mhm now it doesn't start on app launch (thats good) but I recieve error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "1374237141346"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for posting your code. Try this:

```
public static String ALARM_TO_SET = "ALRMTOSEND";
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View view){
     int time = 10 * 1000;

    intentAlarm = new Intent(ALARM_TO_SET);

    alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentAlarm, 0)
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, time, pIntent);


  }
});
```

Your Broadcast receiver should be registered in the Manifest.xml file as:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmRecieverClass">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="ALRMTOSEND" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: But how does the app then know about my Broadcaster class? :o

Comment: So at first, it nearly works well :) In manifest there is a warning `Exported receiver does not require permission` oh sry forgot what was standing here, he calls the AM from beginning on again :/

Comment: Thats alright Phil you don't need to worry about that warning :) Glad it worked for you, try cleaning your Application, reload it and see if it persists, also, delete the app 1st and then do a clean install of the App

Comment: sry edited my post, same problem as before :/ or wait, can it be possible that it is running because I clicked the button, then changed some code, started it again and then it was running from the button click before?

Comment: Ok that was the thing :D A last question, can you tell me how to unregister the AM on button click?

Comment: Cool :) just use alarm.cancel(pIntent) to cancel your alarm where alarm is your AlarmManager's instance and pIntent is your PendingIntent

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `setRepeating` call inside the `onClickListener` method

Comment: changes nothing that the AM starts itself from the beginning :/ I mean I have 2 activitys, and the button for starting the AM is on the 2nd one, but the AM is running since the first one

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a timerTask for this..

Comment: what are advantages of this? the operation has to be done even if the app isnt running

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Button yourButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourId);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View view){
         int time = 10 * 1000;

        intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);

        alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));


   }
  });
```

Comment: doesn't change anything :/ the AM is started with the first activity but I **never** do it in the first activity, it shoudl be in the 2nd where I have the button with the onclicklistener :/ is it maybe the reciever in the androidmanifest?

Comment: Hi Phil, are you referencing the buttons correctly? Could you post some sample code, thanks

Comment: `final Button cmdGo= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        cmdGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view){
                int time = 10 * 1000;

               intentAlarm = new Intent(LoginActivity.context_app, AlarmReciever.class);

               alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
               alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(LoginActivity.context_app,1,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
         }
        });`

Comment: Thats how i reference the button and in the manifest I added <receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever"/>